# empty response body on angular http post

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http, resttemplate

i have a weird behavior in my application.I have a frontend interface (using angular) that send http request to a backend (springboot application) and the backend send a request to external application.When i log the response on my back end everything seems to be ok but in the front end response i get status 200 with empty body. below are some exemple of the code i'am using

Angular code:

`this.http.post(environment.baseUrlBackend + 'api/myapi/' + endPoint, {}, {});`

Java code:

`ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(request.getRequestURI(), request.getQueryString(), userSession), method, userSession.getPostHttpEntityForMaximoQuery(requestBody), String.class);`

i can't seem to find the reason for this especially because i'am not adding any parser after i get the response (i'am logging the same object in both sides)

[image]